# Convert multiple rows with columns in a single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

In SQL Server we have 40 records with 15 columns. I want to merge all these records into one column, meaning 40 * 15 = 600 column in 1 row.

For example, sample table has a few records:

```
sn    Name  city  cntry  conti
------------------------------
1     abc   NYC   USA    NA
2     def   LON   UK     EU
3     xyz   DUB   UAE    ASIA
```

then after merging all the records & get into the one record then it should be like below:

```
sn    Name  city  cntry  conti  sn    Name  city  cntry  conti  sn    Name  city  cntry  conti  
1     abc   NYC   USA    NA     2     def   LON   UK     EU     3     xyz   DUB   UAE    ASIA
```

Comment: To my eye this approach stinks, and you should consider alternatives - if you explain the background those on here may be able to advise. But I suggest the easiest way of achieving what you want would be to implement a series of left joins, starting with an individual row, and joining each subsequent row onto the last, but this will be an extremely brittle approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @SqlText  NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable T1 '

SELECT @SqlText  = @SqlText  + ' INNER JOIN MyTable AS T'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, sn) +' ON T'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, sn) +'.sn =  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, sn) 
FROM MYTable WHERE sn > 1
order by sn 

SET @SqlText  = @SqlText  + ' WHERE T1.sn = 1'

EXEC ( @SqlText )
```

ıt generates this query as result.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable T1  
     INNER JOIN MyTable AS T2 ON T2.sn =  2 
     INNER JOIN MyTable AS T3 ON T3.sn =  3
 WHERE T1.sn = 1
```

Result:

```
sn          Name       city       cntry      conti      sn          Name       city       cntry      conti      sn          Name       city       cntry      conti
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           abc        NYC        USA        NA         2           def        LON        UK         EU         3           xyz        DUB        UAE        ASIA
```

Answer (score 1):

Request looks really weird, but here is one way to do it using `dynamic sql`

```
IF ( Object_id('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL )
  DROP TABLE #Table1

CREATE TABLE #Table1
  (
     [sn]    INT,
     [Name]  VARCHAR(3),
     [city]  VARCHAR(3),
     [cntry] VARCHAR(3),
     [conti] VARCHAR(4)
  );

INSERT INTO #Table1
            ([sn],[Name],[city],[cntry],[conti])
VALUES      (1,'abc','NYC','USA','NA'),
            (2,'def','LON','UK','EU'),
            (3,'xyz','DUB','UAE','ASIA');

DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @col_list = Stuff((SELECT ',sn = max(case when sn = '
                                 + Cast(sn AS VARCHAR(50))
                                 + ' then sn end), Name = max(case when sn = '
                                 + Cast(sn AS VARCHAR(50))
                                 + ' then name end), city = max(case when sn = '
                                 + Cast(sn AS VARCHAR(50))
                                 + ' then city end), cntry = max(case when sn = '
                                 + Cast(sn AS VARCHAR(50))
                                 + ' then cntry end), conti = max(case when sn = '
                                 + Cast(sn AS VARCHAR(50))
                                 + ' then conti end)'
                          FROM   #Table1
                          ORDER  BY sn
                          FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

EXEC('select '+@col_list+' from #Table1')
```

**Result :**

```
+----+------+------+-------+-------+----+------+------+-------+-------+----+------+------+-------+-------+
| sn | Name | city | cntry | conti | sn | Name | city | cntry | conti | sn | Name | city | cntry | conti |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+----+------+------+-------+-------+----+------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | abc  | NYC  | USA   | NA    |  2 | def  | LON  | UK    | EU    |  3 | xyz  | DUB  | UAE   | ASIA  |
+----+------+------+-------+-------+----+------+------+-------+-------+----+------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Here is the dynamic SQL not a table. What should i do instead of table name. That's why i use table alias name for the dynamic SQL

Comment: @ShahinP - Add the dynamic sql in question

Comment: Here is the dynamic SQL code. Please find the solution how to merge all the record into one record.

Comment: Have you check the above sub query